# ion-nav-view not rendering on Android

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to make a simple Ionic application.

I am using the Ionic View app (http://view.ionic.io/) to run the app on my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone running Android 4.4.4.

My application is rather simple. It consists of one screen with a list of category-buttons, and pressing a category-button reveals a list of sub-items belonging to the respective category.

My `index.html` only contains one ion-nav-view element that is supposed to load the html from a template html file, `soundCategories.tmpl.html`.
However, when the application is run on my Samsung Galaxy S3 device the ion-nav-view is not rendered and instead I get my fallback text (ion-nav-view is not supported).

My `index.html` is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Eggly">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Eggly</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.2.4/css/ionic.min.css">    

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/drexler.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animations.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ion-nav-view name="soundCategories">ion-nav-view is not supported</ion-nav-view>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">        </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.2.4/js/ionic.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.2.4/js/ionic-angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script src="app/eggly-app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/soundCategories/soundCategories.js"></script>
  <script src="app/soundCategories/soundbites/soundbites.js"></script>
  <script src="app/common/models/soundBites-model.js"></script>
  <script src="app/common/models/soundCategories-model.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `eggly-app.js`, where my main module is defined:

```
angular.module('Eggly', [
  'ionic',
  'soundCategories'
])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        //abstract state serves as a PLACEHOLDER or NAMESPACE for application states
        .state('eggly', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true
        })
    ;

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs).
        // The reason we default this to hidden is that native apps don't usually show an accessory bar, at
        // least on iOS. It's a dead giveaway that an app is using a Web View. However, it's sometimes
        // useful especially with forms, though we would prefer giving the user a little more room
        // to interact with the app.
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // Set the statusbar to use the default style, tweak this to
            // remove the status bar on iOS or change it to use white instead of dark colors.
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
});
;
```

And here is `soundCategories.js`, where the controller referenced in the ion-nav-view is defined:

```
angular.module('soundCategories', [
'eggly.models.soundCategories'
 ])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('eggly.soundCategories', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                //target the ui-view named 'soundCategories' in ROOT state (eggly)
                'soundCategories@': {
                    controller: 'SoundCategoriesListCtrl as soundCategoriesListCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'app/soundCategories/soundCategories.tmpl.html'
                },
                //target the ui-view named 'soundbites' in ROOT state (eggly)
                //to show all soundbites for all soundCategories
                'soundbites@': {
                    controller: 'SoundbitesListCtrl as soundbitesListCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'app/soundCategories/soundbites/soundbites.tmpl.html'
                }
            }
        })
    ;
})
.controller('SoundCategoriesListCtrl', function SoundCategoriesListCtrl($scope, SoundCategoriesModel) {
   (...)
 });
;
```

When I run the application in a browser or an emulator the contents of my soundCategories template, `soundCategories.tmpl.html` is rendered on screen.

However, when I run the application on my S3 device the template is not rendered.

I have tried downloading my app through the Ionic View app, and also built it with

```
ionic build android
```

and moved the resulting .apk to the device manually.
In both cases the ion-nav-view will not render.

Am I skipping over a step or missing a vital include?

Ps. Some people may notice that my application is based on the Eggly application from Egghead.io, and so it is. I used the Eggly application as a base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why my `<ion-nav-view>` element was not rendering.

I am calling the helper functions for defining the module in the wrong order.

Initially, when I defined my main module in `eggly-app.js` I called `angular.module().config().run();` and the `<ion-nav-view>` element didn't render.

When I switch the order to `angular.module().run().config();` the `<ion-nav-view>` element renders correctly.